# Discord.js async and await

Tags: node.js

When I run the code, I have a error : `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\index.js`
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...

```
d:\GitHub\PROJECTS\codage\projects\BOTS\DiscordJs\AllForOne BotJs\index.js:34
            await interaction.reply(`Server name:${interaction.guild.name}\nTotal members: ${interaction.guild.memberCount}`);
            ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
Process exited with code 1
```

THE CODE

```
    const Client = new Discord.Client({ 
    intents: [
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES
    ]
});
const token = require("./config.json");
const prefix = "!";
const invite = "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=898625628004319232&permissions=8&scope=bot%20applications.commands";

const commands = [
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName("ping").setDescription("resend pong").addUserOption(option => option.setName("utilisateur").setDescription("utilisateur que vous souhaiter mentionner").setRequired(false)),
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName("server").setDescription("Replies with server info!"),
    new SlashCommandBuilder().setName("user").setDescription("Replies with user info!"),
]

Client.on("ready", () => {

    //Client.application.commands.create(data);
    Client.guilds.cache.get("864543215650996234").commands.create(data);

    console.log("Ready!");
});

Client.on("interactionCreate", interaction => {
    if(interaction.isCommand()){
        if(interaction.commandName === "ping"){
            interaction.reply("pong");
        }
        else if (interaction.commandName === 'server'){
            await interaction.reply(`Server name:${interaction.guild.name}\nTotal members: ${interaction.guild.memberCount}`);
        }
        else if (interaction.commandName === 'user'){
            await interaction.reply("Your tag:" + interaction.user.tag + "\nYour id:" + interaction.user.id);
        }
    }
});

Client.on("guildMemberAdd", message => {
    message.channel.send("Bienvenue !")
})

Client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;

    if(message.content === prefix  + "ping"){
        message.reply("pong");
    }
});

Client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if(message.content === prefix + "help"){
        message.channel.send("*le bot est en développement*\n**Les commandes**\n(prefix) + invite | Donne l'invitation du bot")
    }
});

Client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;

    if(message.content === prefix  + "invite"){
        message.channel.send("my invite is " + invite);
    }
});

Client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if(message.content === prefix + "help"){
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor("CraftX#9999", "https://discord.com/assets/3c6ccb83716d1e4fb91d3082f6b21d77.png", "https://github.com/")
            .setColor("#001cfc")
            .setTitle("**Commands list**")
            .setURL("https://discord.js.org/")
            .setDescription("The list of the bot commands")
            .setFooter("Bot in devloppement")
            .setThumbnail("https://discord.com/assets/3c6ccb83716d1e4fb91d3082f6b21d77.png")
            .addField("!help", "__ping__  | send 'pong'\n__invite__ | Donne l'invitation du bot")
            .setImage("https://discord.com/assets/3c6ccb83716d1e4fb91d3082f6b21d77.png")
            .setTimestamp();

            
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]});
    }
});



Client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change one of the paragraphs to this

```
Client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
    if(interaction.isCommand()){
        if(interaction.commandName === "ping"){
            interaction.reply("pong");
        }
        else if (interaction.commandName === 'server'){
            await interaction.reply(`Server name:${interaction.guild.name}\nTotal members: ${interaction.guild.memberCount}`);
        }
        else if (interaction.commandName === 'user'){
            await interaction.reply("Your tag:" + interaction.user.tag + "\nYour id:" + interaction.user.id);
        }
    }
});
```